# opauthを用いたtiwtterおよびfacebook認証で用いるデータ

Tags: php, cakephp

会員制のwebサービスを作ろうとしています。
opauthでtwitterとfacebookのデータは取得できているのですが、認証に関して2点か分からないことがあります。

1. twitterに関しては、「token」「secret」2つの一致を認証の条件にすれば良いでしょうか。
   (twitterはAPIのtokenを無期限にしているため、これで良いのではないかと考えています)
2. facebookに関しては「token」「signature」がログイン毎に変化するので何を認証の条件にすれば良いのしょうか。

詳しい方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけないでしょうか。
お願いいたします。

【facebookから取得したデータ】

```
array(
    'auth' => array(
        'provider' => 'Facebook',
        'uid' => '*****',
        'info' => array(
            'name' => '*****',
            'image' => '*****'
        ),
        'credentials' => array(
            'token' => '*****',
            'expires' => '*****'
        ),
        'raw' => array(
            'name' => '*****',
            'id' => '*****'
        )
    ),
    'timestamp' => '*****',
    'signature' => '*****',
    'validated' => true
)
```

【twitterから取得したデータ】

```
array(
    'auth' => array(
        'uid' => (int) *****,
        'info' => array(
            'name' => '*****',
            'nickname' => '*****',
            'urls' => array(
                'twitter' => '*****',
                'website' => null
            ),
            'location' => '',
            'description' => '',
            'image' => '*****'
        ),
        'credentials' => array(
            'token' => '*****',
            'secret' => '*****'
        ),
        'raw' => array(
            'id' => (int) *****,
            'id_str' => '*****',
            'name' => '*****',
            'screen_name' => '*****',
            'location' => '',
            'description' => '',
            'url' => null,
            'entities' => array(
                'description' => array(
                    'urls' => array()
                )
            ),
            'protected' => (int) 0,
            'followers_count' => (int) 1,
            'friends_count' => (int) 1,
            'listed_count' => (int) 0,
            'created_at' => '*****',
            'favourites_count' => (int) 0,
            'utc_offset' => null,
            'time_zone' => null,
            'geo_enabled' => (int) 0,
            'verified' => (int) 0,
            'statuses_count' => (int) 0,
            'lang' => 'ja',
            'contributors_enabled' => (int) 0,
            'is_translator' => (int) 0,
            'is_translation_enabled' => (int) 0,
            'profile_background_color' => 'F5F8FA',
            'profile_background_image_url' => null,
            'profile_background_image_url_https' => null,
            'profile_background_tile' => (int) 0,
            'profile_image_url' => '*****',
            'profile_image_url_https' => '*****',
            'profile_link_color' => '2B7BB9',
            'profile_sidebar_border_color' => 'C0DEED',
            'profile_sidebar_fill_color' => 'DDEEF6',
            'profile_text_color' => '333333',
            'profile_use_background_image' => (int) 1,
            'has_extended_profile' => (int) 0,
            'default_profile' => (int) 1,
            'default_profile_image' => (int) 0,
            'following' => (int) 0,
            'follow_request_sent' => (int) 0,
            'notifications' => (int) 0
        ),
        'provider' => 'Twitter'
    ),
    'timestamp' => '*****',
    'signature' => '*****',
    'validated' => true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

現状の挙動がどうあれ、OAuth で得られるトークンは後続のリクエストに使う資格情報の一つにすぎません。何らかの理由でリセットすることもあります。

そう考えると、IDプロバイダとなる Twitter や Facebook から提供されるIDである、`$resp['auth']['uid']` を使うのが適切でしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。それではDBには$resp['auth']['uid']を入れるカラムを作成し、認証の際には以下の処理になるという認識で宜しいでしょうか。uidを取得しハッシュ化⇒DBに当該uid(ハッシュ化済)があるかをチェック⇒ログインさせる

Comment: @levi そうですね。ログイン面のセキュリティだけを考えれば別にハッシュ化しなくてもいいとは思いますが。